# bash script change a word into a file

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a file like this:

```
PRODUCT: $name | YEAR: $year | TYPE: $type
PRODUCT2: $name2 | YEAR: $year | TYPE: $type2
PRODUCT3: $name3 | YEAR: $year | TYPE: $type
PRODUCT4: $name4 | YEAR: $year | TYPE: $type3
PRODUCT5: $name5 | YEAR: $year | TYPE: $type
PRODUCT6: $name6 | YEAR: $year | TYPE: $type
PRODUCT7: $name7 | YEAR: $year | TYPE: $type3
PRODUCT8: $name8 | YEAR: $year | TYPE: $type2
```

And i want to change a specifiy field.
For example i want to change the type of *PRODUCT5* from *$type* to *$type2* but i **don't want to replace the whole line**, only the field i'd like to change!
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

`awk` can help:

```
awk '{ if ($1 == "PRODUCT5:") $8 = "$type2"; print }' input
mv output input
```

or `sed`

```
sed -i '/^PRODUCT5/s/$type$/$type2/' input
```

Comment: It works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man!!One question: why you have type $type$??

Comment: @Paolo: to match `$type` at end of line, so that executing twice would not perform the substitution again.

Comment: and if $type has space into the name?? for example: name type2 ?? how can i say to awk that $8 is "name type" and not only "name"??

Comment: @Paolo: the `awk` solution do not work with spaces, but the `sed` one should work. Remove the `-i` option to see output on stdout without modifying the input file. In any case, it is always a good habit to show (a piece of) the real input, and not a pseudo-input.